# Android next/back button to retrieve next/previous record

Tags: android, database, button

I am creating an application that requires a single row of data to be retrieved during each click of a button.

I have created a DataBaseHelper class which calls and retrieves a random record from the database once the activity has been instantiated and the value displayed through a textview. However I am having trouble with retrieving the next or previous record as I can't appear to access the DataBaseHelper class for position values from the button specification mentioned below.

```
Button btn_quotes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_random_quote);
btn_quotes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   public void onClick(View v) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });
```

I have checked on-line and through various articles but cannot find anything suitable. Please help?

In addition,

The instance of the database class is called,

```
DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
```

However the instance within the onCreate method cannot be referenced within the onClick method. This is where I am struggling.

Getting the error:

Cannot refer to a non-final variable myDbHelper inside an inner class defined in a different method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mCursor.moveToNext()`= for next and

`mCursor.moveToPrevious()` = for previous....